# MongoDB , cant connect because he cant find the Hoststring

Tags: java, mongodb, minecraft

Good Moin,
I'm switching to MongoDB from MySQL and well I used the Connection String from the MongoDB Cloud website but it doenst work.

```
 public boolean connect() {
        try {
            client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://root:`password`@provincecluster.ms1am.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
            mcserverdb = client.getDB("ProvinceDB");
            players = mcserverdb.getCollection("ProvinceCollection");
            System.out.println("Connected to Database!");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            //When you end up here, the server the db is running on could not be found!
            System.out.println("Could not connect to database!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient
        at me.moritz.mysql.MongoDB.connect(MongoDB.java:19) ~[?:?]
        at me.moritz.Main.onEnable(Main.java:35) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:370) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:500) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:518) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:432) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:599) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:298) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1074) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:291) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoClient
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:155) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:114) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[?:?]
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: The error is not related to the host string, but to the visibility of mongo classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing ClassNotFoundException. that means your mongo library is not available for it while running the application. check your class path.